# Is it legal to record video in my own dorm room?

Tags: united-states, recording, washington

I live on a campus in Washington State (at a public/state-funded school) and am interested in recording video (no audio) 24/7 in my dorm room without explicitly informing people who come in. I'm not sure if it's relevant but my dorm is paid for in full by a university scholarship.

All the information I could find about recording video in my own house (dorm) said that it was legal, except for areas with a higher expectation of privacy (bathrooms, bedrooms, etc).

I thought all hope was lost but then I came across a case where a person was recorded while using a living room as her bedroom. The judge ruled that even though the room was usually one of the most public rooms in a house, it was being used as a bedroom and therefore was subject to higher expectations of privacy.

I was wondering if this works the other way as well. It is true that my dorm does have a bed in it and it is where I sleep. However, when guests are over, it is not being used as a bedroom, rather a social area. Is this enough to get away without informing anyone?

Comment: They enter with expectations that as a bedroom, it is not being routinely recorded. Very unlikely that you can record them in that setting without informing them.

Comment: You asked this question already.

Comment: I asked a question about recording audio

Comment: I'm not sure someone visiting a dorm room considers it a bedroom upon entering. A lot of things occur in dorm rooms that aren't at all bedroom-related. That said, if it were the other way around, I'm not sure it could operate as the poster describes in the final paragraph - in other words, I'm not sure it could switch on the fly, turning into something other than a bedroom upon guests arriving.

Comment: The purpose of the recording probably matters. The biggest concern would be video of someone undressing or having sex, which is pretty inevitable if it is a 24/7 recording. It also probably matters if you have roommates.

Comment: I don't have roommates and my plan was just to turn off the video if anything happens where someone would obviously be uncomfortable being filmed (friend couch surfing, undressing, etc)

Comment: Why are you recording?

Comment: Anything that happens - like a security camera. If anything happens where someone would obviously be uncomfortable being filmed, I will turn it off.

Comment: I just realized I misread your message. I'm recording just in case. I already own a webcam that I never use so I figured why not secure my room. No specific reason, if everything goes the way I plan I will never need to use the video logs.

Comment: It's a room used primarily for sleeping in. Secondary uses don't change that - it's a bedroom.

Answer (score 1):

Schools typically have rules of conduct and yours may even have rules or notes of cases addressing this very issue, having already determined the parameters. As a public institution in WA, they would probably have administrative rules as authorized or required under various RCWs.